# Se puede ejecutar un metodo de una clase repetidamente en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, clase, metodos

Queria saber como optimizar el código sin la necesidad de que tenga que llamar al metodo para que sume su valor. La clase que tengo cuenta con los siguientes constructores y metodos:

```
class Contador{
    constructor(responsable){
        this.responsable = responsable;
        this.contador = 0;
    };

    static contadorGlobal = 0;
    
    getResponsable = () => {
        return this.responsable;
    };

    contar = () => {
        this.contador++;
        Contador.contadorGlobal++;
    };

    getCuentaIndividual = () =>{
        if(this.contador == 0){console.log(`${this.responsable} no tiene dinero en su cuenta`)}
        else{return console.log(`${this.responsable} tiene en su cuenta = ` + this.contador + ` pesos`);};
    };

    static getCuentaGlobal = () =>{
        return console.log("En el banco hay en total = " + Contador.contadorGlobal + " pesos");
    };
};
```

Se podra hacer un ciclo que me haga esto sin necesidad de instanciar este metodo repetidamente? Ya que se hacen muchas lineas de codigo.

```
const cuentaImanol = new Contador("Imanol");
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
cuentaImanol.contar();
const cuentaJosefina = new Contador("Josefina");
cuentaImanol.getCuentaIndividual();
cuentaJosefina.getCuentaIndividual();
Contador.getCuentaGlobal();
```

Comment: Mejor usa una variable de tipo numérico para contar. Las clases pierden la gracia si no las instancias

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código completo de la clase `Contador`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es posible llamar al método `contar` sin instanciar primero la clase `Contador`, si tienes un método dentro de una clase, solo puedes acceder a ese método si primero creas una instancia de esa clase, por ejemplo:

```js
class Contador {
  constructor() {
    // Inicializo las propiedades en 0.
    this.contador = 0; // Propiedad de la instancia.
  }
  
  static contadorGlobal = 0; // Propiedad de la clase.

  contar() {
    this.contador++;
    Contador.contadorGlobal++;
  };
}

const cuentaImanol = new Contador(); // Creamos una instancia de la clase Contador.

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // Llamo al método "contar()" para incrementar las propiedades (10 veces).
  cuentaImanol.contar();
}

console.log(cuentaImanol.contador);
console.log(Contador.contadorGlobal);
```